# How to make embedded Tcl interpreter keep Tcl_CreateObjCommand for interactive use?

Tags: tcl, interpreter

I'm working on embedding a TCL interpreter in my app and if I add a Tcl script to the command line, my command gets executed and works. So if I have a `*.tcl` script with a command like `my_command 1`, then the myCmd procedure is executed in the library. Then the Tcl prompt appears (%) so I can enter more commands interactively. If I then enter the command again, command is not recognized even though the command has already been created.

The structure of my code is the following. In a library named `My.so`, I have these functions.

```
int myCmd(ClientData store, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj * CONST *objv) {
    if (objc < 2) {
        Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "my");

        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    val = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[0], &valLen);

    // ...

    return TCL_OK;
}

int My_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
    Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "my_command", myCmd, (ClientData) NULL, NULL);
     // ...   

    if (inFile != NULL)
        Tcl_EvalFile(interp, inFile);
    // ...
       
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

And in main.cpp I have ...

```
int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{   
    // ...
    
    interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();

    if (interp == NULL)
        return TCL_ERROR;

    if (Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR)
        return TCL_ERROR;

    if (My_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR)
        return TCL_ERROR;

    return TCL_OK; 
}           
 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);
        
    Tcl_Main(argc, argv, Tcl_AppInit);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create an interpreter in the `Tcl_AppInit()` function; you're given one that's already been made for you by `Tcl_Main()`. (You also don't need to call `Tcl_FindExecutable()` if you're calling `Tcl_Main()`; that does it for you. OTOH, that's pretty much harmless when called twice.)

Comment: `Tcl_Main()` is very much a convenience function for a whole bunch of code that would otherwise go in `main()`. The only reason it isn't just called `main()` directly is that linkers aren't keen on that function being located in libraries.

Comment: Ah, I now understand. I removed the interpreter and all appears fine. Thank you.